# Regarding Active reports 9 Gotham Bold font issue?

Tags: c#, activereports

Initially we developed our project using Active reports 3 and it was fine but to include **Transparency** property when we overlay one image on other, we converted the entire project to Active reports 9. Every thing was fine expect the **Gotham bold** font which used to work well in Active reports 3 Its not working fine in Active reports 9 its getting double bold more darker.

still we have same problem images are getting blurred and **Gotham bold** font is getting more darker in Active reports 9, if we go for Active reports 3 **Transparency** is not working for images and

> We tried the changing the style property **font weight** in text box properties.
>   (Style property in the property grid, remove "font-weight: bold;" from the property value), if we do the same the font is changing to "Arial".

Need some assistance for this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: does this happen in preview?  print?   Also, can please send your report / sample or save the RDF file (document) and send it to our support team so we can look into it.    http://activereports.grapecity.com

Comment: yes for sure, i will generate both the samples in Active reports 9 and in Active reports 3 will forward to your support team.